# Pythagorean Theorem in Java

Tags: java, beginner

I'm new to Java and am following a series of lectures on Stanford's YouTube. I know that the code works, but I'd like to know if it can be improved upon.

```
/*
 * File: PythagoreanTheorem.java
 * Name: Will
 * Section Leader: N/A, I'm freeloading the class off Youtube.
 * -----------------------------
 * This file is the starter file for the PythagoreanTheorem problem.
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class PythagoreanTheorem extends ConsoleProgram {
    public PythagoreanTheorem() {}
    public void run() {
        PythagoreanTheorem myCalculator = new PythagoreanTheorem();
        double a = readDouble("a= ");
        double b = readDouble("b= ");
        if(myCalculator.formula(a,b) == 
            Math.floor(myCalculator.formula(a,b))) {
            println("C= "+(int)myCalculator.formula(a,b));}
        else {
            println("C= "+myCalculator.formula(a,b));}
                      }
    private double formula(double x, double y) {
        double c = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: For those wondering: [get your ACM here](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/)

Comment: "following a series of lectures on Stanford's Youtube" do you have a transcript of the problem statement to include? Did you write the code?

Comment: I wrote the code. The problem asked to code a calculator to calculate the Pythagorean Theorem. The bit about returning an integer if it could was just me being annoyed at .0's.

Comment: Except some weird formatting in your condition an a one line return in `formula` there is nothing much to say. But we do not have much to review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not check the `acm` package but my 2 cents:

### No need to instantate a `PythagoreanTheorem` each time

```
public void run() {
    PythagoreanTheorem myCalculator = new PythagoreanTheorem();
```

`run` is not static, so there already is an instance of `PythagoreanTheorem` availiable in the method, referencable by `this`.

So instead of:

```
if(myCalculator.formula(a,b) ==
```

You can use

```
if(this.formula(a,b) ==
```

### Reuse results

You have a few calls to `myCalculator.formula(a,b)`. While `a` and `b` do not change. You can store the result in a variable.

```
double c = myCalculator.formula(a,b)
if(c == Math.floor(c)) 
....
```